# a click event in JQuery it's not responding

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, soundcloud

I’m trying to do a special HTML5 player using soundcloud API. This code example show how I get tracks from a playlist for each track in the playlist i append into an ul list some li with the cover image of the track.

```
var url = 'http://api.soundcloud.com/playlists/44196539.json?client_id=3b3ca61a7c0afac8a6cfc678a24e23cf';

$.getJSON(url, function(playlist) {
$(playlist.tracks).each(function(i) {
console.log(playlist.tracks[i].title);
$('#liste').append('<li><img value='+playlist.tracks[i].stream_url+'   src='+playlist.tracks[i].artwork_url+'></li>');

     });
  });
```

After that I get them I’m doing this. In the click event the attribute src of the audio player will receive the value of the stream audio. But the problem when i click it's not responding. And my images exists when I’m showing my source code

```
$('img').click(function(){
    var x = $(this).attr('value');
    console.log(x);
    $('#player').attr("src",x+"?client_id=3b3ca61a7c0afac8a6cfc678a24e23cf");
});
```

any ideas to help Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Use [**event delegation**](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

```
$('#liste').on("click" , "img" , function(){
    var x = $(this).attr('value'); 
    console.log(x);
    $('#player').attr("src",x+"?client_id=3b3ca61a7c0afac8a6cfc678a24e23cf");
});
```

Comment: @Downvoters - Please care to comment what mistake i have done then only correct my error.

Comment: Its work thanks a lot but why they are different ?

Comment: You added dynamically li and image tag so event delegation in the context